# Examples to help people understand size and dimensions of rooms.

Tags: user-communication

What are some examples to help users understand the size and dimensions of large items like rooms?

I've found examples such as comparing items to familiar objects (e.g. wallet next to dollar bills) or showing how many items fit within a space. For example:

[image]

[image]

Was wondering if you've seen other better examples. These sort of gives a sense of the space but don't seem very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if it is a room or a large space it is easiest to put a person next to it for reference as it is a natural way for people to want to get a perspective relative to a normal person.

I think you'll find plenty of examples where this is done for things roughly the size of average humans or a couple times greater (but generally not smaller).